# How to draw in runtime created DoubleBufferedPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

I wrote an C# app for drawing vector primitives. For drawing surface I use Draw.DoubleBufferedPanel placed in TabControl. When I cretate new project a new tab page with new Draw.DoubleBufferedPanel is been created. But in click events for the buttons for drowing I use the primary Draw.DoubleBufferedPanel and when I create new tab I can't draw anything in it. What did I have to do to draw in the newly created project?

Comment: Side note: You need to draw in the paint handler.

Comment: I know. I add paint handler for the new DoubleBufferedPanel but it didn't work. I can draw only in the main tab which I created with the designer. My question is what to do if I create 5 different tabs and I want to draw in anyone of them?

Comment: Show a minimal representation of your drawing code - specifically showing how you reference the panel you draw on.

Comment: I've dided with drawing. Now the next problem is that when I draw something I can see it from each tab. For example if I draw circle I can see it and manipulate it from each tab I create after.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your control hierarchy is correct:

- MainForm

  - TabControl
  - TabPage1

    - MyDrawingControl1 : MyDrawControl
  - TabPage2

    - MyDrawingControl2 : MyDrawControl

Then in the paint handler of MyDrawControl (not its instances) you need to paint to only its own surface (graphic) by leafing the clipping intact.

**Update:**

Information about how to implement a control that does some custom drawing can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244392/how-to-correctly-get-a-winforms-button-control-to-draw-custom-text). In general you have to write your own class and inherit from control (or one of its descendants like Button) and implement the OnPaint() method. In OnPaint() you can use the Graphic to paint. The control can be set to DoubleBuffered = true so Winforms automatically applies double buffering around your OnPaint() code.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But how to do this? My paint handler code is: Draw.DoubleBufferedPanel NewDrawArea = sender as Draw.DoubleBufferedPanel;
            eHandler.MouseDown(e.Location);
            NewDrawArea.Invalidate();

Comment: Did you write your own control (class) like "MyDrawControl" above and placed in in every Tab page? Can you post some code so we see that you currently did?